# iPhone XR black screen and hissing noise

Tags: iphone, screen, screen-capture

Today my iPhone's screen randomly went black when I was talking to someone on skype, nothing would work, I tried restarting, etc, plugging/unplugging the charging cable. It was also making a hissing noise while the screen was black.

Everything went away after I used the combination to take a screenshot (volume up button + power button), then the hissing noise went away and my screen started working.

Does anyone know what this was?

Comment: Is there any physical damage (did you drop it,...)?

Comment: No physical damage on the outside, like no cracks, no nothing, I have dropped it a long time ago, but it's always been in a UAG protective case.